# Saving a password in keychain on simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, keychain

In my iPod touch app I am using a library which stores a password in the keychain for future use. Now, this works fine on device but not on simulator.

Is that so there is no key chain in simulator... Shouldn't it point to MAC machine's key chain? Is there any setting I need to do for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

on simulator, the apps arent signed and hence you are having this problem. check out apples 'GenericKeychain' example - this allows for use both in simulator and on device.

[Here it is for your disposal - im using it and works a treat](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Plus..KeychainItemWrapper is not ARCified. If want to use keychain, maybe need to find other libraries or write some codes.

Comment: The above link is broken.  Here's a link to the new [Swift version](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html).  Anyone have a working link to the old Objective-C version?

Comment: Would be nice to have the objective-c version

Comment: Here is objective-c KeychainWrapper still alive on Apple's site. It looks to be a version of KeychainItemWrapper that makes some assumptions (like it hard-codes the identifier, assuming your app will have only one item) - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Use this https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security/ That does exactly what you want.